# Usar a fixture tmpdir do pytest em uma classe

Tags: python, testes-de-unidade

Olá, estou com uma duvida que esta me fazendo atrasar no uso de TDD em meus projetos de estudo. Estou tentando criar um diretório temporário com um arquivo json usando a *fixture* `tmpdir`, porem encontro o seguinte erro ao executar:

```bsh
request = <Response [200]>

    @pytest.fixture(scope="session")
    def tmpdir_factory(request):
        """Return a :class:`_pytest.tmpdir.TempdirFactory` instance for the test session.
        """
>       return request.config._tmpdirhandler
E       AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'config'

.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/_pytest/tmpdir.py:152: AttributeError
```

Eu possuo a seguinte *fixture* em meu arquivo `conftest.py`:

```py
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def json_file(tmpdir_factory, request):
    fp = tmpdir_factory.mktemp('data').join('answer.json')
    create_json(fp, request.txt)
    return fp
```

O `request` é outra *fixture* que criei para baixar o conteúdo de uma API, e em meu arquivo `test_case.py` esta assim:

```py
class TestCase:
    def test_create_file(self, json_file):
        print(json_file)
        assert 0
```

O `assert 0` esta ali apenas para gerar o erro e me mostrar o resultado do diretório criado como nos exemplos do pytest. Todas os meus demais testes e *fixtures* funcionam sem problemas, apenas esse para criar um diretório temporário usando o `tmpdir_factory`, o mesmo ocorre se apenas usar `tmpdir` dentro da classe.

Answer (score 0):

Resolvido, o problema se encontra na *fixture* `request`, ela é utilizada pelo escopo `session` de forma direta. Para resolver bastou alterar o nome da *fixture* `request` para `request_json`. Outro ponto é que as demais *fixture* devem estar no escopo `session`.